# How to deal with HUGE (32GB+) multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: database, windows, multidimensional-array, theory

I have a multi-dimensional array of strings (arbitrary length but generally no more than 5 or 6 characters) which needs to be random-read capable. Currently my issue is that I cannot create this array in any programming language (which keeps or loads the entire array into memory) since the array would far exceed my 32GB RAM.

All values in this database are interrelated, so if I break the database up into smaller more manageable pieces, I will need to have every "piece" with related data in it, loaded, in order to do computations with the held values. Which would mean loading the entire database, so we're back to square one.

The array dimensions are: [50,000] * [50,000] * [2] * [8] (I'll refer to this structure as X*Y*Z*M)

The array needs to be infinitely resizable on the X, Y, and M dimensions, though the M dimension would very rarely be changed, so a sufficiently high upper-bound would be acceptable.

While I do have a specific use-case for this, this is meant to be a more general and open-ended question about dealing with huge multi-dimensional arrays - what methods, structures, or tricks would you recommend to store and index the values? The array itself, clearly needs to live on disk somewhere, as it is far too large to keep in memory.

I've of course looked into the basic options like an SQL database or a static file directory structure.

SQL doesnt seem like it would work since there is an upper-bound limitation to column widths, and it only supports tables with columns and rows - SQL doesn't seem to support the kind of multidimensionality that I require. Perhaps there's another DBMS system for things like this which someone recommends?

The static file structure seemed to work when I first created the database, but upon shutting the PC down and everything being lost from the read cache, the PC will no longer read from the disk. It returns zero on every read and doesnt even attempt to actually read the files. Any attempt to enumerate the database's contents (right-clicking properties on the directory) will BSOD the entire PC instantly. There's just too many files and directories, windows can't handle it.

Comment: Is this a sparse matrix?

Comment: Yes. Well, sort of. Zero is an actual value in my array. Remember that it is an array of String values.
The array itself is the result of a computation, so a zero value must be retained, as that is the computed answer for that index. But if there *was* no answer at an index (returned null) the index does not need to exist.

Comment: Another option is to use an OS-managed memory-mapped file, in a 64-bit process this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I'm looking now at the MSDN docs for memory-mapped files. It looks like I can do this in VB, which is cool, cause that's what my computation program is already using. But it also looks like it's designed to work for pieces of *really big, single files*. And I have no idea how I would store all this as a single file.

Would memory mapping work with millions of files, located in hundreds of thousands of nested subdirectories?

Comment: _"Would memory mapping work with millions of files"_ - no, it's intended for single-files - but because it supports really huge files it's useful in your case. Using multiple files is a bad idea because it means having to go through the filesystem layer every time you resolve and open a file, whereas reading/writing pages inside a single file is much faster (as the file is always _already_ open: the OS doesn't need to check permissions, etc).

Comment: _"And I have no idea how I would store all this as a single file."_ - this isn't a problem: if your arrays are always the same size then you can define a bijection mapping from a complete multidimensional address (i.e. a sequence of array indexes) to exact file offsets, while storing variable-length data that won't fit inside each "cell" to a structure at the end of the file (which means adding new strings should be fast as appending data is fast).

Comment: _"And I have no idea how I would store all this as a single file." _ - if your arrays lengths can vary then you'll need to use something like a _pages and extents_ system ([similar to how SQL Server's `.mdf` file-format works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver16), which is the same as practically every RDBMS today (and don't even think of using "flat-files" - those don't scale to support large amounts of variable-length data)